# JHipster: Dependency convergence error for org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0

Tags: java, spring, maven, jhipster

I am new to JHipster and I am getting the error "Dependency convergence error for org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0" on a freshly generated JHipster project with no changes to the code. I will post the contents of my .yo-rc.json file in a comment because Stack Overflow does not like pure code. there is not much else to say about this error

Comment: here is .yo-rc.json file contents:

Comment: {
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "helloworld",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },

Comment: "jhipsterVersion": "6.8.0",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "jhipster",
    "packageName": "helloworld",
    "packageFolder": "helloworld",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mariadb",
    "searchEngine": false,

Comment: "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": true,
    "jwtSecretKey": "YjM2NjEwYjBlNTE4NWVjZmFmNTIzZDI2ZmIxM2IyYWJhZTQ3YTJiZmFmNzgyMWQ4MTBmMTZlN2Q4YTEyOWNjNWM1YTJjNTQ2MDYzMWUyZWU0YTUwNWU3M2I4MzQ3ZTFkMDE5ZDcwYTYyNjViMDMwYzE4ZGY0OTcwMmZlMDE0ZjU=",
    "embeddableLaunchScript": false,
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientTheme": "none",

Comment: "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "creationTimestamp": 1587930109196,
    "testFrameworks": ["protractor"],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-vuejs2",
        "version": "1.1.12"
      }
    ],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": ["en", "ru"],
    "blueprints": []
  }
}

Comment: Can you please edit you question and include your `yo-rc.json` in your question and use code formatting to make it readable. You can also run `jhipster info` and copy the output into your question. The {} button will do code formatting.

Comment: I also got this message but it's only a warning not an error.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your `.yo-rc.json` and reformatted it:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "helloworld",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.8.0",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "jhipster",
    "packageName": "helloworld",
    "packageFolder": "helloworld",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mariadb",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": true,
    "jwtSecretKey": "YjM2NjEwYjBlNTE4NWVjZmFmNTIzZDI2ZmIxM2IyYWJhZTQ3YTJiZmFmNzgyMWQ4MTBmMTZlN2Q4YTEyOWNjNWM1YTJjNTQ2MDYzMWUyZWU0YTUwNWU3M2I4MzQ3ZTFkMDE5ZDcwYTYyNjViMDMwYzE4ZGY0OTcwMmZlMDE0ZjU=",
    "embeddableLaunchScript": false,
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "creationTimestamp": 1587930109196,
    "testFrameworks": ["protractor"],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-vuejs2",
        "version": "1.1.12"
      }
    ],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": ["en", "ru"],
    "blueprints": []
  }
}
```

Then, I installed the latest version of JHipster:

```
npm i -g generator-jhipster
```

I ran `./mvnw` after it finished generating, and it starts just fine for me.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'jhipster' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8080/
    External:   http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    Profile(s):     [dev, swagger]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I suspect your problem is you're using [generator-jhipster-vue2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-vuejs2), which appears to be a fork of JHipster. It's not supported by the JHipster developers.

See [jhipster-vuejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-vuejs2) if you want to use JHipster with Vue.js.

Comment: I'm sorry. If I can't reproduce the problem, it's very difficult for me to fix it.